# Inspecting the values of constant or variable tensors during debug

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging, tensorflow

I implemented a model in TensorFlow (Python) that I previously programmed in C++ using Eigen, where it worked as expected. But the model is not working as expected in Python, and it's probably because I am defining tensors incorrectly or I am mixing up dimensions.

I am trying to get a feel for the problems by using Visual Studio's (2017) debugger (if a different IDE is better for this then I'm all ears, but I would prefer to stick with VS), but tensors do not evaluate to anything - and I can understand this because the tensor defines an operation and not a data object (well it only produces a data object after calling a `session.run`).

However, constant and variable tensors - and any other tensors built solely on top of such tensors - come with predefined data. So hey, why not be able to inspect the value through the debugging UI?

So my question: is there a way to inpect the data with some extension?

For example, if I was working in C++ and with Eigen, I can use Eigen.natvis as described [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Developer%27s_Corner#Debugging_tips). Anything similar for TensorFlow? It's not just a matter of seeing the evaluated value, either. It would be nice to see things like the shape, etc... while debugging.

I would also be open to other debugging techniques of TensorFlow code, if anyone has a good suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

TensorFlow includes `tfdbg`, a debugger for TensorFlow models, where you can step through each execution step, check values, stop on NaN, etc. See the programmer's guide [TensorFlow Debugger](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger) and [The Debugger Dashboard](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/tensorboard/plugins/debugger/README.md) for more information.

`tfdbg` can be a bit cumbersome to setup and use though. A quick alternative to check intermediate values is to [use `tf.Print` operations](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-tf-print-in-tensorflow-aa26e1cff11e). TensorFlow includes a few other [debugging operations](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/control_flow_ops#Debugging_Operations) that you may find useful to check for some basic things.

EDIT: Another tool that can be useful is [eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager). This allows you to use TensorFlow operations as if they were regular Python operations (they return the result of the operation instead of the graph object), so it is a good way to check if some particular code does what you expect.

Comment: Thanks jdehesa.  I am still looking into this as you have a few examples to try here.  Will leave some feedback on how I found each to be useful.

Comment: @AOK, Would you please share the latest information? Could you get useful information from jdehesa's suggestion?

Comment: `tfdbg` was a bit tough to set up as explained, so I skipped it. `tf.Print` seemed sufficient. Furthermore, in Visual Studio, using `a = sess.run(Tensor)` or `a = Tensor.eval()` - which I could do from the interactive window (works like the immediate window but for Python), and I can see `a` in my local variables watch. This seemed to be the simplest approach with what is available.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT In addition to AOK feedback, I have added a reference to [eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager) in the answer, since it can also be useful to debug pieces of code or experiment with the API.

Comment: I think the ideal situation, where VS is concerned, is to create a module that does what eager execution does, but onto the watch window. Preferably, rank-1 tensors can be displayed the same way as 1-dim containers, rank-2 as matrices (like Eigen does), and rank-3 and up will allow to select a permutation of 2-d slices of the tensor to display like a matrix over a list of the other dimensions. This is beyond me to program, and I could not find some kind of TF contributor request message board.